# Getting FileAttributes over https / http in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

The System.IO.File.GetAttributes method is valid for only files on the local system.
In my application I was trying to access a file attribute over https://. Please  let me know if there is any such class/method (in .net), to get a file attributes over http(s).

Also, it will be great if there is any such Windows CommandPrompt command to achieve the same.
Do let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please clarify what "over http" means in your case: get attributes of "file" located at "http:/server/path/file" OR proxy remote shell traffic over HTTP/HTTPS?

Comment: by over http or https  I meant the file path is like: https://www.abc.com/congrats.jpg , So here is  file name: congrats.jpg whose attributes is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. It would be huge security violation.

You could write a WCF Service that returns the attributes you are interested in, however.

Or you may be interested in setting up a [WebDAV](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/webdav/authoring/filesystem) share.

Comment: Thanks paul for clarifying. I am actually trying to get attributes of a file for any website wherever & not the only website i'm hosting. I Guess this won't be possible.

Comment: @FlopScientist, keep in mind that in large number of cases there is no file behind url that look like file :)